# Routine name maximum length in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran

Does anyone know if there is a maximum length for routine names and variable names in Fortran 90?

Comment: @francescalus: Fair enough.  Strange, though... if you want all questions, wouldn't you follow the [fortran*] tag?  *shrug*

Answer (score 20):

Yes, the Fortran standards define a maximum length for names of things, including both routines and variables.  In Fortran 90/95 the maximum length was 31 characters, in Fortran 2003 it is now 63 characters.  In earlier versions it was as short as 6 characters.  Your compiler may allow (non-standard) longer names.